# SQL Database Data Dictionary Inquiry

Tags: sql, database, data-dictionary

I'm a university student who is completely new to SQL and I don't know what I'm doing, so go easy on me. I have been given an assignment to design a Facebook-like database for a website for people who read books. I have made a very basic data dictionary which gives the general idea.

[image]

Is this a valid approach? Is there a better way of doing this? I'd appreciate any feedback I can get.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would say good to see your efforts.
Here I would suggests you bit enhancements. Instead of maintaining different tables for 
books_liked,books_read,wish_list, etc., you can maintain same with the help of flags in the master table books. This is to normalize  your data.

eg. flg_liked, flg_wish_list, flg_read

Comment: I thought you could do something like that, but I didn't know how I could implement that. I know I'm asking for a lot but could you provide a small example?